# How to display all information in toString

Tags: java, tostring

I have two classes: `Position` and `Order`. In `Position` class, fields like: `name`, `price`. In `Order` class field: `quantity`. My problem is how to display: `name`, `price` and `quantity` together in `Order` class. I thought about delete arraylist and make another one with position and quantity but I doubt it would help me.

```
package programming.com.pl;

public class Position  {

private String name;
private double price = 0;


public Position(String name, double price){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public String toString(){
    String str = String.format("%4s,%4s", name,price);
    return  str;
}
}

public class Order {
private int quantity;
final private ArrayList<Position> positions = new ArrayList<Position>();
private int addedPosition;


public Order(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

private double calculateProduct() {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
        sum = positions.get(i).getPrice();
    }
    return sum;
}

double sumOrder() {
    double sum = 0;
    for (Position x : positions) {
        sum += calculateProduct();
    }
    return sum;
}


void addPosition(Position p) {
    if (!positions.contains(p)) {
        positions.add(p);
    } else {
        quantity++;
    }
}

void deletePosition(int index) {
    positions.remove(index);
}


public String toString() {
    System.out.println("Order is: ");
    for (Position p : positions) {
        System.out.println(positions.toString());
    }
    return "Order sum is: " + sumOrder();
}
}
```

Comment: The indentation of your code and the lack of closing braces makes it hard to understand whether `Order` is inside `Position` or not. Can you please [edit] your question to remove the ambiguity?

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't have `System.out.println` inside a `toString` method. You probably meant to create a `StringBuilder` and append to it all the `p.toString()` (not `positions.toString()`) and then apppend `sumOrder` as well?

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to display `quantity` for each position?

Comment: Thank you for pointed out of my mistakes. I will change toString method. Yes I wanted to display quantity for each position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already are overriding `toString` method in `Position` class so you just need to call that `toString` method on the position object when iterating the position objects from inside your `Order` class' toString() method.

And as @Federico points out in the comments you shouldn't `System.out.println` from `toString` methods. Just append to a string the details you require displaying and return that string.

You can achieve your desired result like so:

```java
public class Position {
    .
    .
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%4s,%4s\n", name, price);
    }
}

public class Order {
    .
    .
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Order details: \n");
        sb.append("Quantity: ").append(quantity).append("\n");
        for (Position p : positions) {
            sb.append(p);
        }
        sb.append("Order sum is: ").append(sumOrder());
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution it's ok but it doesn't work properly. I need to display quantity for each position. In your solution I have single quantity for all positions :(.

Comment: You can append the quantity inside the loop. But honestly, if you need quantity to be part of each Position model it like so, keeping the quantity field inside Position class.